# Insert image after each list item

Tags: css

What would be the best way to insert a small image after each list element?  I tried it with a pseudo class but something is not right...

```
ul li a:after {
  display: block;
  width: 3px;
  height: 5px;
  background: url ('../images/small_triangle.png') transparent no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 360, accepted):

The easier way to do it is just:

```
ul li:after {
    content: url('../images/small_triangle.png');
}
```

Comment: And also some problems with this in firefox

Comment: Be aware that IE7 sucks.

Comment: @RichardGarside By "doctype", do you just mean something like this at the top? `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: The problem with this method is that you cannot provide an alternate text for the image, which (depending on what the image is used for) may reduce accessibility.

Comment: But you can't give height/width to the image using this.

Comment: @RichardGarside according to caniuse, the only problem with IE8 is the fact it can only be one colon - IE 8 does not support `class::after` but will support `class:after`

Comment: Can you change the dimensions of this inserted image (`<img>` ?) or would you need to insert it as background in that case?

Answer (score 95):

Try this:

```
ul li a:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 3px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent url('../images/small_triangle.png') no-repeat;
}
```

You need the `content: "";` declaration to give your generated element content, even if that content is "nothing".

Also, I fixed the syntax/ordering of your `background` declaration.

Comment: I like this technique over the simpler ones because it gives you control over the size of the image using background-image-size.

Comment: You'd also need this if you want to horizontally center an image. You can't position it to `left: 50%` because it wouldn't be aligned to the middle. Use `left: 0; width: 100%` and set the background position to 50% instead. Works well for me. Thanks for the tip about the required `content` attribute.

Comment: This was the better answer and also, if you're using bootstrap, you may need to use display: inline-block; otherwise the image will be under each li item and not on the right or left

Comment: Looks great but to display the image inline (after the "li"), it should be "display: inline-block".

Comment: and also `background-size: container`

Answer (score 12):

For IE8 support, the "content" property cannot be empty.

To get around this I've done the following :

```
.ul li:after {
    content:"icon";
    text-indent:-999em;
    display:block;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background:url(../img/icons/spritesheet.png) 0 -620px no-repeat;
    margin:5% 0 0 45%;
}
```

Note : This works with image sprites too

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is that the :after psuedo-element requires the content: property set inside it. You need to tell it to insert something. You could even just have it insert the image directly:

```
ul li:after {
    content: url('../images/small_triangle.png');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ul li + li:before
{
    content:url(imgs/separator.gif);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution to do this:

```
li span.show::after{
  content: url("/sites/default/files/new5.gif");
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```