# How to put the image inline on right hand side of text field in Bootstrap framework?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using `Bootstrap framework v3.0.1`

Following is the HTML code part, where I have a problem:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 control-label">Enter Field ID from challan<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span> :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_id" id="field_id"/><img src="img/demo_img.png" width="20" height="20"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I want to put the image exactly in front of text field having Id "trans_id". I want to add this image after two white spaces.

In above code the image is coming on next line of text field.

Can someone help me in this regard?

Comment: You should recreate the problem on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/) and include it in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Use `form-group` and `input-group`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 control-label">Enter Field ID from challan<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span> :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_id" id="field_id"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <img src="img/demo_img.png" width="20" height="20"/>
    </span>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**working fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/YXkUT/652/

Answer (score 1):

Add the image as Background/content to the element before which you wanted it to be displayed with after/before tag in css

For instance,

```
.form-control:after{}
```

Refer these links,hope it would help you.

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/

```
.name::before {  content: "Name: ";}
```

the output of content will be

```
<div class="name">Chris</div>

Would render like this:

Name: Chris
```

[Insert image after each list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946403/insert-image-after-each-list-item)

```
    ul li:after {
    content: url('../images/small_triangle.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this.Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/245gd60x/

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 control-label">Enter Field ID from challan<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span> :</label>
   <div class="col-sm-5">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_id" id="field_id"/>
       <img src="img/demo_img.png" width="20" height="20"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,nesting the col-sm-5 into 2 parts with some space between them:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 control-label">Enter Field ID from challan<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span> :</label>
   <div class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_id" id="field_id"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1">
            <img src="img/demo_img.png" width="20" height="20"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```