# Add an icon next to item text in <ul> in <nav>

Tags: javascript, material-design, materialize

How can I add an icon next to item text in `<ul>` in `<nav>`

http://jsfiddle.net/h96y7sw8/10/

The basic way is:

```
<li><a href="layout/pages/index.html"><i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i>Test</a></li>
```

But when I have `<ul>` in `<nav>` it doesn't work anymore.

I am sorry, I tried to use the snippet, but it didn't work.

Comment: but it seems you have icon in your jsfiddel that you have shared. What is the problem. Locally make sure you have material is added correctly

Comment: I can also see the icon. It is displayed a little weird because it is a `block` element but if you change it to `display: inline` it looks basically as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert image after each list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946403/insert-image-after-each-list-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works! For alignment, you can add additional CSS.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
            <li><a href="layout/pages/index.html"><span>Test <i class="material-icons md-24">face</i></span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse">
            <i class="material-icons" style="margin-left: 35%;">menu</i>
        </a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/s34z0dun/

HTML:

```
 <li><a href="layout/pages/index.html">Test</a> <i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i></li>
```

CSS:

```
.side-nav a {
display:inline;
}
.side-nav i.material-icons{
  color:black;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  left: -25px;
  top: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for crazy % inline styles, Materialize already has it covered. Simply add `.left` to your icon.

```
<li>
   <a href="layout/pages/index.html"><i class="material-icon left">shopping_cart</i>Test</a>
</li>
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/GRpxomb).