# Appear an image in the button when hover

Tags: html, css

This is a code from the W3Schools. It is an animated button which when you hover appears a narrow next to the text. You can see that under the `.button span:after {content: '\00bb'...}`. How can I replace the narrow ('\00bb') with any image I want? Probably is very easy but i am new and i can't figure it out. Thank you.

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

**.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb'**;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 55px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<h2>Animated Button</h2>

<button class="button"><span>Hover </button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert image after each list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946403/insert-image-after-each-list-item)

Answer (score 0):

Your actual content pertains to some character. You can load a different icon from a font here or upload an image. Then you have to leave the content blank and put the image in the background.

```
content: "";
background:  url('../images/your-image.png') no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass image and also It could be a gradient

```
content: url('Image url');
```

you can refer [https://css-tricks.com/](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/)
for learn more about content