# Aligning list texts to the centre of bullet icon

Tags: html, css, reactjs, alignment, vertical-alignment

Trying to align the list texts to the svg icons of the bullets in an unordered list.

Tried a lot of the solutions available on the internet but setting `vertical-align: middle` does not do anything and setting `display: flex; align-items: center;` to the parent element removes the icons, for some reason.
Any help would be appreciated.

I did this in React but the React part is working fine(I think?) so sending the HTML and CSS snippets.
HTML

```
<div className="registration-form">
      <div className="form-text-container">
        <div className="form-text">
          <h1>Stay Updated!</h1>
          <p>Join 6000+ product managers receiving monthly updates on:</p>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span className="list-text">
                Product discovery and building what matters
              </span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span className="list-text">
                Measuring to ensure updates are a success
              </span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span className="list-text">And much more!</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="form-image-container">
        <SignUpImageDesktop className="form-image" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.registration-form {
  display: flex;
  height: 60vh;
  width: auto;
  padding: 2.5%;
}

.form-text {
  padding: 6%;
}

.form-text p {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-text ul {
  list-style-image: url("../assets/images/icon-list.svg");
  padding-left: inherit;
}

.form-text ul li {
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.list-text {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-image {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

The output is like-
[image]
Notice the bullets.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reducing the `line-height` from `.form-text ul li` or, even better, not use `list-style-image`.

A better approach may be use something like `before` with `content: url()`, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946403/insert-image-after-each-list-item) (just change the `after` for `before`)

With this, you can use `display: flex;` and `align-items: center` to align everything

Comment: Hi Galeno, really appreciate your answer. Using before with content: url() worked the same but 'display: flex; align-items: center' is still not working and I still cannot find a way to align the texts with the icons/bullets unfortunately.